# How to add a small icon to item listview when that item is on click?

Tags: android, listview, icons, selected

I have a ListView and each item have a TextView.

I would like add a small icon when user click in that item. (when user click other, icon hide and show in the other)

any ideas, examples or tutorials?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need a custom ListViewAdapter.  This website has a good tutorial: 
http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: Thanks @jack57, but in that tutorial they implements an item ListView with differents images all time. I want to appear an icon in the item when user click in it.

Comment: Not every tutorial is going to be cookie-cutter perfect for your needs.  You need a custom adapter, so you might have to use logic to figure how this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could put an OnClickListener on each list item that associates the icon with that item and programmatically add the icon to its layout, while removing it from the previous' layout. So you'll want to have a variable that holds the current layout that is associated with the icon, and when a new item is clicked you remove the icon from that layout, then set the variable to this new item's layout.